# JQuery Dialog - only load when button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

Using JQuery Dialog http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation
The dialog box appears whenever the page loads I only want it to appear when 'Remove Invoice' is clicked.

i've tried:`<input id="RemoveInvoice" type="button" value="Remove Invoice" onclick="ConfirmDeleteInvoice()" />`

then putting the actual JS inside a ConfirmDeleteInvoice function:

```
  function ConfirmDeleteInvoice() {
      //  $(function () { //removed this line and added the above line
        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height: 140,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Are you sure you want to delete this invoice": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
    });
    }
```

ERROR: JavaScript runtime error: 'ConfirmDeleteInvoice' is undefined

Sorry still a beginner at JS so please bear with.
Thanks

Comment: where are you putting your javascript in? head?

Comment: try: `$('#RemoveInvoice').on('click', function(){});` and put everything from ConfirmDeleteInvoice inside that anonymous function and remove the onclick from the element.

Comment: you could just put `ConfirmDeleteInvoice()` function inside of a click handler.. btw i dont know if you pasted the code in but your it has some extra brackets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got an extra trailing `});` right before your last closing brace, take that out and it'll work.

Also, in my fiddle you'll see I've added the click event in jQuery, as `onclick` inside HTML is considered bad practice. I did this by adding:

```
$("#RemoveInvoice").click(ConfirmDeleteInvoice);
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/P4VHw/